# How to set up Varnish locally on a Mac OS with MAMP Pro?

Tags: homebrew, mamp

I'm trying to make Varnish work on my local Mac with MAMP Pro (running a Drupal website). I have installed Varnish with Homebrew

```
brew install varnish
```

So far so good. Then I start Varnish with the following command :

```
sudo varnishd -a 127.0.0.1:8080 -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/drupal.vcl -s file,/tmp,500M
```

The varnish child start and I start to monitor with :

```
varnishstat
```

MAMP Pro is set to port 80 which is the conf I have in my .vcl file. The problem is Varnish does not cache the page when I go to my http://drupal.local website (All the caching conf from Drupal is properly set up as it works on a centOS server).

Any idea about what I'm missing ?

Comment: Varnish “not working” sounds like a configuration issue and not exactly a problem with macOS. .  Perhaps this is a better fit for [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Allan, it actually works because when I visit 127.0.0.1:8080, I See Varnish in the Header of the response. I may have a port pb, but what I'm reading is very confusing. I tried to move to NGINX but no success here.

Comment: So, Varnish server is “up” but not answering requests?  It definitely points to a config issue.  By any chance, are you running a firewall?

Comment: I don't think so. I just use MAMP Pro with Apache on port 80 and Varnish on port 8080 and using the official Drupal.vcl file

Comment: Don’t think it’s a config issue or a firewall issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's a firewall issue

Comment: Maybe the folks over at [Drupal SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) can assist?  I don’t think you’re going to find many Varnish/Drupal experts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution and what I was missing. My vhost was in HTTPS and working with Varnish it's easier to work with HTTP.

Here is all the step that might help someone :

Make sure that Apache in MAMP Pro is running on port 80.

In the VCL file make sure that Varnish targets port 80. Mine was looking like that :

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "80";
}
```

Then I start varnish with the following command (varnish running on port 8080) :

```
sudo varnishd -a :8080 -T localhost:6082 -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/drupal.vcl -s file,/tmp,500M
```

When I visit `http://my-vhost.local:8080/node/1` varnish is properly caching the page. If I go to `http://my-vhost.local/node/1`, I see the page without varnish.

To clear the varnish cache of the page I just do this command :

```
curl 'http://my-vhost.local:8080/node/1' -X PURGE
```